# Why is "wong" a bad word?

Tags: offensive-language

I just use "wong" as if I am saying "wrong" without the "r". For example "You are wong. try again" However, this word is moderated in roblox chat several times.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wong) and other dictionaries define *wong* as an obsolete term meaning *field, meadow.*

Is there some other meaning of this word?

Comment: Have a look at the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wong) definition. I found this using [OneLook](https://onelook.com/) dictionary search. Voted to close due to lack of research.

Comment: And the lesson from this is, always spell words correctly!

Comment: What do you mean "some *other* meaning"? What do you think the *first* meaning is?

Comment: I thought it was just a mispelled version of ""wrong""

Comment: @user067531 I don't like that edit. It's a transparent attempt to get round the 'please include your research' requirement, and the definition is neither relevant to the meaning the OP is asking for, or done by the OP.

Comment: It happens to reference a well-known [racist remark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Calwell#Calwell_and_racism).

Comment: @marcellothearcane - improve  questions by editing so as to help    users, especially new ones,   is something recommended by the the CoC. As for my edit, the purpose was, in case it is not clear enough, to show that the term is not present in all major dictionaries  with a derogatory meaning, but just with a neutral, obsolete one. From which the validity of OP request!!!

Comment: Before more people vote to close this question, I would like to post the [meta-thread](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13422/) we have regarding it for their potential consideration. I wrote an answer regarding most of my own rationale for reopening it that might be worth reading before the final decision is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider my English to be fairly good, and as soon as I saw “wong“, I told myself it was either a typo for "wrong" or someone's last name. Discovering its subculture meaning was bit of an eye-opener.

But discovering the history behind  *wong* proved to be even more fascinating. As Merriam-Webster attests, *wong* is an obsolete Old English word for *field*, and *meadow*

> Middle English, from Old English *wong*, *wang*; akin to Old High German *-wang* field

If further proof was needed

> **WONG**, **WANG**, a termination of local names in England,
>   as [Basfordwong](https://www.british-history.ac.uk/thoroton-notts/vol2/pp230-231), Cornerwong, is the A.S. *wang*, *wong*, a plain, field, allied to Dan. […] *Wong* occurs frequently in Norfolk.
>   <sub>*[Local Etymology: A Derivative Dictionary of Geographical Names](https://books.google.it/books?id=s1OpF1IdcgQC&pg=PA299&dq=wong%20etymology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0-6vD-NzkAhUIsaQKHSK9ByMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=wong%20etymology&f=false)* 1859</sub>

However, I suspect the majority of Anglophone speakers would be most familiar with Wong as a surname. It is said that Wong is the 3rd most common Chinese name in the US and the most common Chinese last name in Canada. However, in old Britain, it was also an *English* surname derived from *[geong](http://www.majstro.com/dictionaries/Old%20English-English/geong)* meaning *young*.

> [Wong family history](https://www.archives.com/genealogy/family-history-wong.html) in England begins with Thomas Wong, married at St. Martins in the Field in Westminster, England, at the end of 1699.

Here is the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wong) entry

> 1. *Noun*
>      **wong** (plural wongs)
>
> (obsolete, except in placenames) A field or other piece of land.
>
> 2. *Verb*
>      **wong** (third-person singular simple present *wongs*, present participle *wonging*, simple past and past participle *wonged*)
>
> (gambling) To enter a betting game, particularly blackjack, when the odds are favorable.
>
> 3. *Noun*
>      **wong** (plural wongs)
>
> In the game of pai gow, a hand in which the double-one or double-six domino is used with a nine, making the hand worth eleven points rather than the usual one.

In Old Javanese, it had the following meanings

> 1. person, human being
> 2. people, society
> 3. adult
> 4. successful person
> 5. physical characteristics of a person
> 6. subordinate, follower

It's a pity a word with such noble and humble origins has been appropriated and sullied, and its very presence banned in some gaming communities.

In conclusion, the word *wong* has several different meanings, mostly obsolete, but in recent years it has taken on the vulgar overtones mentioned in Green's Dictionary of Slang and in Urban Dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/qth2qpq) *wong* is an AmE slang expression that means:

> (US) the penis.
>
> - 1948    [US]    in Randolph & Legman Ozark Folksongs and Folklore (1992) II 656: *He wrapped his thumb around his wong*.

possibly from the AmE ***[wang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/e4mn7dy#sn1)***:

> - c.1930  [US]    N. Kimball Amer. Madam (1981) 167: *A worn down male who can only sit with his flabby wang and think about how it was when he was well hung and horny.*

also ***[whang:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/nqax3lq#sn4)***

> (orig. US) the penis, usu. large.
>
> - 1934    [US]    in Randolph & Legman Ozark Folksongs and Folklore (1992) I 496: *When the Lord made father Adam, / They say he laughed and sang, / He sewed him up the belly / With a little piece of whang. [...] Said he, ’Tis but eight inches, / So I’ll just let it hang, / And he left on Adam’s belly / That little piece of whang*.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning the Yiddish [schlong](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/schlong) which Lexico defines as "A man's penis". It may help explain how the O got there. It might be an acronym combining wang with schlong.